# Ubuntu client wants to mount NFS share on old CentOS server: access denied by server while mounting

Tags: ubuntu, centos, mount, nfs

These are the OS versions of the machines:

```
server# lsb_release -idrc
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 4.6 (Final)
Release:        4.6
Codename:       Final
```

and

```
client$ lsb_release -idrc
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

On the server, the exported share is:

```
server# nfs-export --list
Directory       Permissions             Hosts
/share          rw                      *
```

So on the client, I tried to mount that share as follows (10.1.1.1 is the server's IP address):

```
client$ sudo mount -t nfs 10.1.1.1:/share /share
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.1.1.1:/share
client$ sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 10.1.1.1:/share /share
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.1.1.1:/share
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=2 10.1.1.1:/share /share
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.1.1.1:/share
```

Other CentOS machines on the same LAN can mount the share just fine, so I thought it might be a permission problem. To check, I did this:

```
server# tail /var/log/messages
Dec  7 14:51:40 server mountd[3556]: authenticated mount request from client.mylan.com:712 for /share (/share)
Dec  7 14:51:42 server mountd[3556]: authenticated mount request from client.mylan.com:712 for /share (/share)
Dec  7 14:51:45 server mountd[3556]: authenticated mount request from client.mylan.com:712 for /share (/share)
```

...which looks just like the lines successful mount operations by other CentOS machines.

I looked at a few other questions with the same error message but couldn't find anything that resolved the issue, e.g.:

- [The server's CentOS version doesn't have the `showmount` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275093/55900)
- [The server's CentOS version doesn't have the `exportfs` command`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106124/55900) and I believe since other clients can mount fine, that's already taken care of

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this bug hits you:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1582854

Seems they are going to fix that soon via updates. So far comment #3 says that this should work:

```
mount -t nfs -v o nfsvers=2 ...
```

For debugging your problem you could also check that

```
rpcinfo -p 10.1.1.1
```

shows all the needed services and their ports are reachable by the client. Note that portmap services may be restricted via `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`