# How to allow specific Proxmox LXC containers to mount NFS shares on the network?

Tags: nfs, apparmor, proxmox

This question is very similar to *[How to fix ”mount.nfs: access denied …“ when trying to mount a NFS share exported by a Proxmox 5 machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396678/access-denied-when-trying-to-mount-nfs-share)*.

On a Proxmox LXC container I'm trying to mount a NFS share located on a different physical machine on the network. In `/etc/fstab` I've got this line:

```
192.168.0.4:/mnt/Pool1/homes     /home     nfs     auto,rw,hard     0 0
```

Running `mount /home` fails with the following output:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.0.4:/mnt/Pool1/homes
```

Output of `mount -v /home`:

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Jun 17 15:29:02 2018
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'hard,vers=4.2,addr=192.168.0.4,clientaddr=192.168.0.166'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.0.4:/mnt/Pool1/homes
```

Each time I run the `mount` command, a line is added to `/var/log/messages`, like this one:

```
Jun 17 15:26:47 userserver-01 kernel: [  256.620770] audit: type=1400 audit(1529249207.168:19): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed type match" error=-13 profile="lxc-container-default-cgns" name="/home/" pid=2938 comm="mount.nfs" fstype="nfs" srcname="192.168.0.4:/mnt/Pool1/homes"
```

Obviously Proxmox uses AppArmor, and AppArmor denies the NFS mount operation  (`apparmor="DENIED"`). It looks like AppArmor is using profile `lxc-container-default-cgns` (the log file shows `profile="lxc-container-default-cgns"`). I found that profile in `/etc/apparmor.d/lxc/lxc-default-cgns`.

I suppose I can edit `/etc/apparmor.d/lxc/lxc-default-cgns` an perform the changes necessary to allow NFS. However, this would allow NFS for *all* containers. Is it possible to allow NFS **only for specific containers**?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible. Simply create a new profile (based on `lxc-container-default-cgns`) and use it for the specific containers. So first run

```
cp -i /etc/apparmor.d/lxc/lxc-default-cgns /etc/apparmor.d/lxc/lxc-default-with-nfs
```

Then edit the new file `/etc/apparmor.d/lxc/lxc-default-with-nfs`:

- replace `profile lxc-container-default-cgns` by `profile lxc-container-default-with-nfs`
- put the NFS configuration (see below) just before the closing bracket (`}`)

### NFS configuration

Either write

```
  mount fstype=nfs*,
  mount fstype=rpc_pipefs,
```

or (being more explicit)

```
  mount fstype=nfs,
  mount fstype=nfs4,
  mount fstype=nfsd,
  mount fstype=rpc_pipefs,
```

and finally run `systemctl reload apparmor`.

### Use the new profile

Edit `/etc/pve/lxc/${container_id}.conf` and append this line:

```
lxc.apparmor.profile: lxc-container-default-with-nfs
```

Then stop the container and start it again, e.g. like this:

```
pct stop ${container_id} && pct start ${container_id}
```

Now mounting NFS shares should work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed question and answer.  It helped me solve the same problem.  Know why proxmox doesn't enable nfs/cifs by default or why there no GUI option for this?

Comment: Glad it helped @GavinHill .. [They say](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/nfs-file-system-mount-problem-apparmor.31706/) *”NFS mounts are disabled for security reasons“*. However, there's a new GUI option allowing NFS mounts. You need a *privileged* container, then enable the container option ”nfs“.

Comment: @myrdd where is the nfs container option? i'm using 6.3-2

Comment: In 7.-10, under Options | Features.

Comment: Does this NFS AppArmor profile require a privileged container?

Comment: @DerekMahar I'm sorry, I can't answer you that question as I'm not using this method anymore. Instead, I'm mounting the NFS share on the *host* (Proxmox VE) and pass it as a directory to the container.

Comment: @myrdd I also mount NFS, SMB, or SSHFS shares on the Proxmox host and then mount these into each container.  However, this introduces the problem of mapping host user and group IDs to those inside the container (see https://www.itsembedded.com/sysadmin/proxmox_bind_unprivileged_lxc/).  I find that Incus (formerly LXD) solves this ID mapping problem better than does Proxmox (see https://linuxcontainers.org/incus/docs/main/faq/#can-i-bind-mount-my-home-directory-in-a-container).