# Trouble Mounting NFS on Alpine Container (Proxmox)

Tags: mount, nfs, alpine-linux, proxmox

Trying to mount an NFS share on an Alpine (3.15.3) lxc on Proxmox (7.1-10).
Following the [Alpine docs](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_nfs-server) for NFS, I have added `nfs-utils`, and `rc-start nfsmount`.
The entry in fstab is

```
192.168.11.192:/volume1/media /mnt/media nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr 0 0
```

As root, I try mounting with `rc-service nfsmount start`.  Response is:

```
 * Starting NFS sm-notify ... [ ok ]
 * Mounting NFS filesystems ...mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
mount: permission denied (are you root?)
 [ !! ]
 * ERROR: nfsmount failed to start
```

Am I running into the same issue described in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450308/how-to-allow-specific-proxmox-lxc-containers-to-mount-nfs-shares-on-the-network), where Proxmox is disallowing it?
I am fairly new to Proxmox and have inherited the box with several VMs that are running critical apps.  I'm hesitant to make changes to the host unless it's required.
Does editing `/etc/apparmor.d/lxc/lxc-default-cgns` seem like the right way to address the root cause or is there something else I should check first?